# Exception to wildcard postfix catch alias to let dovecot store email

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp, dovecot

I have configured postfix to read alias maps from PostgreSQL (`virtual_alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-virtual-alias-maps.cf` ), every domain I've configured has a wildcard/catch-all rule.

Making a more specific alias to redirect email to a new email (e.g. external provider) is possible but I have no clue how to tell postfix (to tell dovecot) to store e-mail for specific e-mail addresses.

Every tutorial online that I've found assumes that I want to redirect e-mail to some real user on the system, **I do not** want a few hundred new users on my system. I think I have virtual users.

Just for further clarification, these redirections are what I want to achieve. (I tried using username instead of a full e-mail address in the aliases already but that didn't work, the e-mails weren't stored, so there must be more to this):

```
user@domain.com -> user@domain.org
user2@domain.email -> user2 (SMTP user's mailbox)
@domain.com -> catchall (SMTP user's mailbox)
@domain.email -> catchall (SMTP user's mailbox)
@domain.net -> user@external.com
user2@domain.com -> user2@domain.email
[... and a few hundred more ...]
```

The solution must also work with unicode email addresses, I'm already really annoyed by Postfix's stupid LATIN1 PGSQL driver that isn't mentioned anywhere, it doesn't even convert to punycode when the character set isn't LATIN1.

If you need any other details please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there really need for PostgreSQL backend for aliases? This is fairly simple with a Berkeley DB

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

In this example, `.com` and `.net` are internal and `.org` is external:

```
user@example.com   user@example.org
user2@example.com  user2
user2@example.net  user2
@example.com       catchall
@example.net       catchall
```

Think addresses and destinations as simple pairs, getting rid of complicated chains like:

```
user2@domain.com --> user2@domain.net --> user2
```

Comment: So just having an username as the destination should put the e-mail in the user's mailbox and I have to debug it, thanks! `Is there really need for PostgreSQL backend for aliases?` - It allows me to create a nice graphical user interface for managing them.